# Visual Studio Will Not Edit Script Task

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, script-task

I've had trouble trying to get an Excel file to connect to this SSIS package so I've uninstalled and reinstalled VS2019, Integration Services, and Access Server 64bit a half dozen times.

This most recent time I opened the SSIS package I created that started this whole mess and I got an error that it was incompatible.  Not sure how as I created it using the exact same packages!

Now it will not allow me to Edit Script on any Script Tasks, even new Script Tasks in a completely new file!

Answer (score 0):

After some time on Google I found some older posts with similar issues where Miscrosoft Visual Studio Tools for XXXX didn't uninstall properly and wasn't registered properly upon reinstall.

I went into Add/Remove Programs found I had tools for 2017 and 2019.  I clicked Modify on them, and select Repair.  Upon repairing them both the scripts could then be edited again.